# sixth dimensional String array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a sixth dimensional String array in java and after populating a fourth dimensional array manually I wanted to use Array.fill() to save myself time and well a tedious amount of work. I've tried numerous online "solutions" as well as for/enhanced for loops to no avail. I keep receiving exception 3130 (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String). Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ed.

Here is my code:

String colors[][][][][][] = new String[4][4][4][4][4][4];

```
    for (String[][][][][] Red : colors) {
        Arrays.fill(Red, (String) "Red");
        for (String[][][][][] Blue : colors) {
            Arrays.fill(Blue, (String) "Blue");
            for (String[][][][][] Green : colors) {
                Arrays.fill(Green, (String) "Green");
                for (String[][][][][] Yellow : colors) {
                    Arrays.fill(Yellow, (String) "Yellow");
                }
                for (String[][][][][] Orange : colors) {
                    Arrays.fill(Orange, (String) "Orange");
                }
                for (String[][][][][] White : colors) {
                    Arrays.fill(White, (String) "White");
                }
```

Comment: You should probably improve your question, like adding the actual code you wrote. You can read more about asking better questions in [help]

Comment: My apologies. here it is.

Comment: I updated my answer. But I am curious: why on earth do you need a 6D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type of exception is thrown to

> indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.

(From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html))

To understand why, you first have to think about what that code means.

`String[][][][][][]` is an array of arrays of arrays that contain arrays containing arrays containing strings. So, yeah.

When you iterate over `colors` with the enhanced for loop, you take away the leftmost layer, and `Red` contains a 5-dimensional String array, i.e an array containing an array containing an array containing an array containing strings. But `Arrays.fill` does not take away the outer layers for you, but tries to fill the topmost, i.e. an array holding 4-dimensional Arrays, with strings. Which leads to the exception.

What you need to do instead is unwrap layer after layer of the array-onion and fill the actuals String arrays like so:

```
    String colors[][][][][][] = new String[4][4][4][4][4][4];

    for(String[][][][][] layer1 : colors){ // Iterates over all 5D arrays in colors
        for (String[][][][] layer2 : layer1){ //Iterates over all 4D arrays in the 5D arrays
            for (String[][][] layer3 : layer2){ // 3D
                for (String[][] layer4 : layer3){ // 2D
                    for (String[] actualArray : layer4){ //actual string arrays
                        Arrays.fill(actualArray, "something"); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So here you are iterating over all 5D arrays, iterate over all the 4D arrays in each of them etc. until you finally fill the 1D arrays with Strings using `Arrays.fill

Comment: Thank you Gumbo, I ran your code and it worked. One question is can I add a different color to each of the dimensions? This is for a Rubik's cube program.

Comment: @Edward I think you didn't quite understand what a multi-dimensional array is or when to use it.  As I said, it is an array containing arrays, you can't fill the _dimensions_ with anything because they are just dimensions. What you _can_ fill are the 1024 arrays of String type you have in your construct. For representing the six sides of a cube, you don't need a 6D-array that can hold 4096 values, but just 6 arrays, one for each side. Or maybe a 3D-array (`String[6][3][3]`) where you can access the fields on the cube like `colors[side][column][row]`

Comment: Once again,I thank you Gumbo for your time and explanation.I do struggle with the concept of multidimensional arrays after 3D as we only covered 2D in my classes.The reason I'm trying to do it this way is because I have a friend that made a rubik's cube game using a 6D array and I figured it would be a good challenge for myself.